# KendoUI DatePicker validation when multiple date fields are on a page

Tags: validation, kendo-ui

I'm looking to validate date fields on a page, which is simple (see [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ufimom/4/edit)). BUT, when a page has multiple date fields on a page things start to get wacky...

See [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ufimom/279/edit) and play around with invalid dates.

The invalid message doesn't know which input to bind to, causing error messages on the wrong inputs. Is there a way to trigger the correct input field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining a validator for the form, define a validator for each date as actually you want to validate the fields and not the form as a whole. You can do it as:

```
$(".datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
$(".datepicker").kendoValidator({
    rules   : {
        //implement your custom date validation
        dateValidation: function (e) {
            console.log("e", e);
            var currentDate = Date.parse($(e).val());
            //Check if Date parse is successful
            if (!currentDate) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    },
    messages: {
        //Define your custom validation massages
        required      : "Date is required message",
        dateValidation: "Invalid date message"
    }
});
```

Your JSBin modified [here](http://jsbin.com/ufimom/282/edit)

Comment: Hah. So simple. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was banging my head against the wall because all the examples on the KendoUI page make a reference to a form as if it is a required thing. Plus one to your answer.